# How do I get more details on a full text catalog error?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, errors

I have an error that is repeatedly generated on a SQL Server 2005 instance running the databases for MS Team Foundation Server.

```
 'Severity 16' occurred on INSTANCENAME
```

Looking in the SQL Server logs gives me

```
 Errors were encountered during full-text index population for table or indexed view '[TfsWorkItemTracking].[dbo].[WorkItemLongTexts]', database 'TfsWorkItemTracking' (table or indexed view ID '1810105489', database ID '14'). Please see full-text crawl logs for details.
```

And the actual full-text crawl log (\MSSQL\LOG\SQLFT0001300005.LOG) gives me:

```
 Error '0x800b0100' occurred during full-text index population for table or indexed view 

 The component 'MSFTE.DLL' reported error while indexing. Component path 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\MSSQL\Binn\MSFTE.DLL'
```

If I rebuild the full-text catalog like so...

```
 ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [TeamFoundationServer10FullTextCatalog] 
 REBUILD
```

The error will stop happening for a while, but it will start up again days later. I have searched for hours and cannot figure out what is causing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: This [troubleshooting section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142487%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) might help. Have you tried to check that db for consistency errors?

Comment: No luck with integrity checks, and no luck with the troubleshooting section unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

According to a post in the MSDN forums, SQL Server 2005 (and probably earlier) contained a flaw that results in the error.  This was reported by "A Fellows" in his problem resolution back in 2010.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9626c8f8-9171-4625-a9c0-ef72628066b9/fulltext-error-indexing-rows-with-jpgs

In part he says: "Well microsoft looked into it and with SQL2008 it works properly, with SQL2005 it doesn't ... (but) ... SQL2008 full text has been rewritten and works as it should."

If you are still on SQL Server 2005 and still stuck with the problem, then he also offers a workaround of sorts for SQL Server 2005.